# If statement in Access Report

Tags: ms-access, if-statement

I have created a report in Access.
Inside the report is a textbox whose name is "CountOfVotes".  The box uses the formula =Count(*). This adds up the number of votes awarded for a performance. There are several different performances.
I have created another textbox called "Round". I want to write an IF, ELSEIF, ELSE statement that uses the number of Votes to calculate what round a performance has reached.  For example

```
If CountOfVotes >3 Then
   Output "You have reached Round 3"
ElseIf CountOfVotes =2 Then
   Output "You have reached round 2"
Else
   Output "You have only reached round 1"
End If
```

What is the correct syntax to write this procedure in the Code Builder??

Many thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *Choose* in an expression like this as *ControlSource* for your textbox:

```
=Choose(Count(*),"You have only reached round 1","You have reached round 2","You have reached Round 3")
```

or a little fancier if this is quite fixed:

```
="You have " & IIf(Count(*)=1,"only ","") & "reached round" & Str(Count(*))
```

This, however, will not be blank (Null) for a count of zero.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  Ah yes, this is a very eloquent solution. Many many thanks